# Random Forest Probabilistic Prediction vs majority vote

Tags: random-forest, python, scikit-learn, aggregation, bagging

Scikit learn [seems to use](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) probabilistic prediction instead of majority vote for the model aggregation technique without an explanation as to why (1.9.2.1. Random Forests).

Is there a clear explanation for why?  Further is there a good paper or review article for the various model aggregation techniques that can be used for Random Forest bagging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such questions are always best answered by looking at the code, if you're fluent in Python.

`RandomForestClassifier.predict`, at least in the current version 0.16.1, predicts the class with highest probability estimate, as given by `predict_proba`. ([this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.16.1/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L465))

The documentation for `predict_proba` says:

> The predicted class probabilities of an input sample is computed as
>   the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The
>   class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same
>   class in a leaf.

The difference from the original method is probably just so that `predict` gives predictions consistent with `predict_proba`. The result is sometimes called "soft voting", rather than the "hard" majority vote used in the original Breiman paper. I couldn't in quick searching find an appropriate comparison of the performance of the two methods, but they both seem fairly reasonable in this situation.

The `predict` documentation is at best quite misleading; I've submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4640) to fix it.

If you want to do majority vote prediction instead, here's a function to do it. Call it like `predict_majvote(clf, X)` rather than `clf.predict(X)`. (Based on `predict_proba`; only lightly tested, but I think it should work.)

```
from scipy.stats import mode
from sklearn.ensemble.forest import _partition_estimators, _parallel_helper
from sklearn.tree._tree import DTYPE
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
from sklearn.utils import check_array
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted

def predict_majvote(forest, X):
    """Predict class for X.

    Uses majority voting, rather than the soft voting scheme
    used by RandomForestClassifier.predict.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
        The input samples. Internally, it will be converted to
        ``dtype=np.float32`` and if a sparse matrix is provided
        to a sparse ``csr_matrix``.
    Returns
    -------
    y : array of shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]
        The predicted classes.
    """
    check_is_fitted(forest, 'n_outputs_')

    # Check data
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")

    # Assign chunk of trees to jobs
    n_jobs, n_trees, starts = _partition_estimators(forest.n_estimators,
                                                    forest.n_jobs)

    # Parallel loop
    all_preds = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=forest.verbose,
                         backend="threading")(
        delayed(_parallel_helper)(e, 'predict', X, check_input=False)
        for e in forest.estimators_)

    # Reduce
    modes, counts = mode(all_preds, axis=0)

    if forest.n_outputs_ == 1:
        return forest.classes_.take(modes[0], axis=0)
    else:
        n_samples = all_preds[0].shape[0]
        preds = np.zeros((n_samples, forest.n_outputs_),
                         dtype=forest.classes_.dtype)
        for k in range(forest.n_outputs_):
            preds[:, k] = forest.classes_[k].take(modes[:, k], axis=0)
        return preds
```

On the dumb synthetic case I tried, predictions agreed with the `predict` method every time.

Comment: Great answer, Dougal!  Thanks for taking the time to explain this carefully.  Please consider also going over to stack overflow and answering [this question there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899274/scikit-learn-randomforestclassifier-probabilistic-prediction-vs-majority-vote).

Comment: There's also a paper, [here](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/421.pdf), which addresses probabilistic prediction.